# Include additional fields in Woocommerce email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site. The email notification that the website admin receives when a new order is placed only displays the 'email:' and 'tel: data under the 'Customer Details' heading.

I would like to add another standard field (company name) that the customer has filled in at the checkout phase to appear in the email - how do I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the hooks that were added in WooCommerce 2.3

```
function so_229971110_add_meta_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){
   $prodmetaa = get_post_meta($order->id, "_company_name" , true);
   echo "Company Name: " . $prodmetaa;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'so_229971110_add_meta_to_email', 20, 3 );
```